# Rabbitmq - start_consuming may not be called from the scope of another BlockingConnection or BlockingChannel callback

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, pika

I have two python processes, one consumer process and one producer process. Each process will start a rabbitmq connection and spawn multiple consumer/producer threads. Each thread will create a channel in the connection and perform the message sending and receiving logic.

This is my consumer thread

```
def consumer_thread(connection, routing_key):
    channel = connection.channel()
    result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
    queue_name = result.method.queue
    channel.queue_bind(exchange="test", routing_key=routing_key, queue=queue_name)
    thread_name = current_thread().name

    def process(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(f"{thread_name} received {body}")

    channel.basic_consume(process, queue=queue_name, no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

This is my producer thread

```
def producer_thread(connection, routing_key, sleep_time):
    channel = connection.channel()
    thread_name = current_thread().name
    count = 0

    while True:
        count += 1
        channel.basic_publish("test", routing_key=routing_key,
                              body=f"msg {count} from {thread_name}")
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

And I start a rabbitmq connection using

`connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))`

However, when I run my code, for the first message received at consumer thread, I am getting this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\app\cortex-bin\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\app\cortex-bin\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\app\cortex\background\core\scratch\test.py", line 18, in consumer_thread
    channel.start_consuming()
  File "D:\app\cortex-bin\Python36\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1817, in start_consuming
    'start_consuming may not be called from the scope of 'pika.exceptions.RecursionError: start_consuming may not be called from the scope of another BlockingConnection or BlockingChannel callback'
```

For all subsequent messages, they can be received by the consumer threads just fine.

May I know what's causing this exception? Thanks.

Comment: The bug is described here: https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/927

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a Pika connection from multiple threads ([comment](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/927#issuecomment-366428321)). Your threads must start their own connection and channels.

Comment: I have another question. Currently I have several message producing threads that only publish messages infrequently  (e.g every 6 hours, or every 24 hours). As for the consumer thread. It doesn't take very long to process each message (within heartbeat interval), but most of the time the connection is idle as no message being published. In both cases, do I have to constantly publish heartbeat messages in order to keep the connection alive? Will the rabbitmq server take care of the heartbeat sending?

Comment: Rather than tack on a question to an existing one (that nobody will learn from), please either ask a new question here at StackOverflow or on the [`pika-python`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pika-python) mailing list.